# JButton alignment in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, alignment, jframe

I am making a pig latin translater using JFrame in Java. Here's my problem; I have a "quit" button that closes the program; that doesn't matter, but what does is I have no control over its alignment (or any other component). I tried using `quit.setAlignmentY(BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT);` in the hopes that that would align it to the bottom of the page, but nothing changed. Some help here, please?
In case anyone needs it, here's the code;

```
    public class Main extends JFrame{  
        private static JLabel label, result;  
        private static JTextField english;  
        private static JButton quit;  
        private static String originalResult = "Translated to pig latin: ";  
        private static ArrayList<String> beginningSymbols = new ArrayList<>();  
        private static ArrayList<String> endingSymbols = new ArrayList<>();  
        //prompt for string to translate, display final result  
        public Main(){  
            super("Pig Latin Translator");  
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());  
            setVisible(true);  
            setSize(600, 300);  
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
            translatingHandler th = new translatingHandler();  
            label = new JLabel("Enter a phrase to translate into pig latin, then press enter:");  
            english = new JTextField(15);  
            result = new JLabel(originalResult);  
            quit = new JButton("Quit program");  
            english.addActionListener(th);  
            quit.addActionListener(th);  
            quit.setAlignmentY(BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT);  
            add(label);  
            add(english);  
            add(quit);  
            add(result);  
            english.requestFocus();  
        }  

        public static void main(String[] args){  
            new Main();  
        }
...
}
```

The JButton quit is the one I'm trying to align to the bottom of the page. Thanks!

Comment: Solution: read the [tutorials on use of layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and start using them. FlowLayout is fine for some simple things but you'll need to use some of the other ones to solve this, likely nesting JPanels each using its own layout manager. For instance a BorderLayout can be used for placing a JPanel in the bottom position of the GUI and you can place your exit JButton in that bottom JPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are using `FlowLayout`. If you take a look at [FlowLayout tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) it is mentioned that

> The FlowLayout class puts components in a row, sized at their
>   preferred size. If the horizontal space in the container is too small
>   to put all the components in one row, the FlowLayout class uses
>   multiple rows. If the container is wider than necessary for a row of
>   components, the row is, by default, centered horizontally within the
>   container.

If you insist on using FlowLayout align your components.

Anyways take a look at [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html). For your task appropriate layout managers will be  `BorderLayout`.

But if you need something very flexible use `GridBagLayout` or [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) but they are a little complex to use.

So as @HovercraftFullOfEels suggested try avoiding them.

Comment: Better to avoid GridBagLayout if you can and only use it if you must. Better to use simpler layout managers in nested JPanels.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: any specific reason to avoid it other than it's complexity.

Comment: Mainly due to its complexity, especially for a newbie to use of layout managers. Most complex layouts can be made with nested components. Also MigLayout is a better grid creator than Gridbaglayout.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the confusing world of Java Swing.  You probably want to look into layout managers.  Specifically, [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) might be of interest.